# Glassfish doesn't open/debug project in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

Glassfish seems not running. It stays like in first image below for a long time.

Why could this be happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the server logs. See if you can start it from the command line. Try a clean server installation. Verify the port is detected correctly. If the server startup freezes, you can use `jstack` to get a thread dump and try to figure out what's causing the freeze.